# Need help writing TAB to a toString method

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, tostring, jgrasp

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class example
{

    private int numbers[]; //instance variable
    private String result;

    public example()
    {
        numbers = new int[10];
        Arrays.fill(numbers, 42);
    } 

    public example(int[] array)
    {
        numbers = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    }

    //get and set methods
     public void setNumbers (int numbers) 
    {
        //setMethod
        this.numbers = new int[numbers];
    }

     public int [] getNumbers()//get method
     {
        return numbers;
     }


    public  String toString()
    {
        String result = new String();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
            result = result + list[i] + "\n";

    }
}
```

Hey guys, so I'm having trouble with my `toString()` method. My `toString()` method is supposed to return a `String` that contains the elements of my instance array with tab characters in between.  So for this is what I have

Answer (score 5):

The `TAB` character in java is represented by: `\t`

So everything you need is to replace this character right here on your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        result = result + list[i] + "\t";
```

Comment: I get the error "bad operand types for binary operations" when i compile it for my for (i=0;..statement

Comment: `numbers` is an array, so you'll need to use `numbers.length`

Comment: Just added the length to the second for operand

Comment: Thanks this was more helpful than you think :)

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark as so, otherwise stackoverflow won't ever know that your problem has been solved. Consider up vote answers that were somewhat useful. This helps other users with similar questions to find answers more easily

Answer (score 1):

The tab character can be represented in strings by `"\t"`. This is called an *escape sequence*, and there's a defined set documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Note. It's good practise to use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to efficiently construct your string, and then call `toString()` on that to get your final string to return.

Answer (score 0):

For `TAB` character use `\t` and your code is with many comipation errors.

First I noticed is your are not returning anything from the `toString` method so it won't compile. You must return a `String` as the return type of `toString` method is `String`

And in your `for` loop you are using `numbers` (which is an array in your code) with `<` operator so it is not proper, instead you should use `numbers.length`

You should write like this:

```
public  String toString()
{
        String result = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            result += list[i] + "\t";
        return result; //return the string that you have made.

}
```